# Doing a calculation on two Ruby multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, activerecord-calculations

This is for my own educational growth as my code works, but I am sure that there is a better way to code it. I have been looking up various Ruby .map, .inspect, etc and can't seem to find an explanation online that I can wrap my head around. Here is what I am trying to do.

I have two arrays. The first array has multiple parts with two values per part. They are taken from a table that maps job responsibilities to job positions and the map has the weight that that responsibility holds for that position. So, for instance, the job responsibility of knowing how to code would be weighted 10 for a coder, but a 1 for an office assistant.

The second array has multiple parts with two values per part. They are taken from a table that maps an employee's answer to how well they feel they fit that responsibility.

I get the first array by this code:

```
@responsibility_weights = ResponsibilityMap.where(job_position_id: job_position_id).pluck(:id, :weight)
 => [[4, 10], [5, 8], [6, 9]]
```

As you can see, this creates an array for only the responsibilities for a given job position, and fills the array with the ID of the responsibility_map and the weight that it holds in that position.

I get the second array by this code:

```
@responsibility_answers = ResponsibilityAnswerMap.where(application_id: application_id).pluck(:responsibility_map_id, :answer)
 => [[4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 3]]
```

As you can see, this creates an array for the given answers by an employee and fills the array with the ID of the responsibility_map and the given answer.

Looking at these two arrays, you should see that they are filled with 3 groups, and each group has the same ID as the first number.

The employee is weighing themselves on a scale of 1-5, 1 being not at all and 5 being the best. So, I figure it is best to take the weight of the question and divide it by 5 to get how many points each ranking should get then multiply that by the answer they gave to get the result of how many points they should get for that responsibility. I then want to add all the points that they get and divide by the total points that could be gotten in order to get a percentage that they ranked themselves in that job position. Clear as mud yet? I hope I am explaining well.

**Question: **

This is where my question comes in. The code I have listed below works and does the job. But, I am sure there is a more concise way to get the result. Can anyone please educate me and any future web searchers on how you would do it? (I hope that I put in enough information to hit keywords for any future web searchers to find this question and the related answers.)

NOTE: This code does take in an array of multiple employee applications, calculates the grade and then updates the application with the grade. Just in case anyone is looking at this and wondering about those parts of the code.

```
def calculate_responsibility_grade(job_position_id, applications_array) 
    calculate_responsibility_grade = false

    @responsibility_weights = ResponsibilityMap.where(job_position_id: job_position_id).pluck(:id, :weight)

    #This is type of concise coding I am trying to find out how to use below
    @total_weight = @responsibility_weights.map{ |key, value| value}.sum 

    i = 0
    loop do
        if applications_array[i].nil?
            break
        end

        #Grabs new employy answers
        @responsibility_answers = ResponsibilityAnswerMap.where(application_id: applications_array[i]).pluck(:responsibility_map_id, :answer)

        #Resets scores to 0 from first previous run through    
        @score = 0
        @total_score = 0
        @responsibility_weights.each do | key1, weight|
            @responsibility_answers.each do | key2, answer|
                if key1 == key2     # Checks if the two keys match meaning they are for the same responsibility
                    @score = (weight/5.to_f) * answer    # Divides the weight by the number raking (1-5) to get the value of each rank, then multiplies by the answer the employee gave
                    @total_score = @newScore + @score  # Adds the score for that answer to total score
                end
            end
        end
        
        responsibility_grade = (@total_score/@total_weight) * 100  # Gets percentage

        # Updates application with new grade.
        Application.find(applications_array[i]).update(responsibility_grade: responsibility_grade)

        i = i + 1
    end
    
    calculate_responsibility_grade = true
end
```

Thank you in advance for your time on educating me and future researchers.

Comment: This would be a better question for codereview.stackexchange.com. Also, I don't think your line `@responsibility_answers = ResponsibilityAnswerMap.where(application_id: applications_array[i]).pluck(:responsibility_map_id, :answer)` will work. You'd need to pluck just the `responsibility_map_id` here I think?

Comment: This smells like the kind of aggregate you should be creating in the database instead of by looping through the data in Ruby/whatever language.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips, not a full reimplementation:

1. Separate database access from logic

```rb
# fetch from DB up here

# let's say these are the values we get
weights = [[4, 10], [5, 8], [6, 9]]
answers = [[4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 3]]

# Logic only here, no DB
# ...
# ...

# let's say these are the results we get
application_grades = { 5 => 12.3, 7 => 32.4 }

# now do DB writes
```

2. break up operations, examples below

```rb
# associate weights to answers
id_to_weights = weights.to_h
answers_to_weights = answers.map do |id, answer|
  id_to_weights[i] ? [answer, id_to_weights[i]] : nil
end.compact.to_h

# compute answer scores
answer_scores = answers_to_weights.map { |answer, weight| weight * answer / 5.0 }
# sum all answer scores
total_score = answer_scores.sum
# normalize weights
grade = total_score.to_f / id_to_weights.values.sum * 100
```